# Is it possible to apply for a visa from a country that is not my country of origin?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, netherlands

I live in the Netherlands as a student and have a valid resident permit. I intend to travel to the US and I have an Indian passport. Is it possible to apply for a visa here through the Indian Embassy?

Comment: One generally applies at the consulate responsible for one's *place of residence*, not the home nation. I'm not aware that the US does it differently. So go to the US consulate or embassy for the Netherlands.

Comment: Why "Indian Embassy" rather than the US consulate?